# How do I handle path/route parameters in Swashbuckle?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, swagger, swashbuckle

I have a controller where I get the ID from the route.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{vehicleId}")]
public InfoDto GetInfo([FromUri] VehicleDetailsRequest request)
{
   return ...;
}
```

The `VehicleDetailsRequest` object looks like this (the Validator is from FluentValidation):

```
[Validator(typeof(VehicleDetailsRequestValidator))]
public class VehicleDetailsRequest
{
    public int VehicleId { get; set; }

    public string Lang { get; set; }
}
```

I can query this action as I expect with `http://localhost/controller/123?lang=sv` but my swagger documentation looks like this:

[image: Swagger documentation with duplicated parameters]

How can I get Swashbuckle/Swagger to only show me one `vehicleId` but still keep the FluentValidation?

I'm using Swashbuckle 5.6 and .Net Framework 4.6.2.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, there is something wrong with action method signature. 
The parameter from the URL should be present in the action method parameters.

Also, if you want only lang in query string, then it should also be present as a parameter in the action.

*Please note that if you specify object in the action parameters, all its properties would be forming the query string.*

So, your action method should like below:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{vehicleId}")]
public InfoDto GetInfo(int vehicleId, [FromUri] string lang)
{
   return ...;
}
```

This should help you to resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I realize that this would fix it but I'm also using FluentValidation and would like to keep doing so. I've updated the original question.